# Create Google Sheets chart based on amount of times date appears in the cell

Tags: date, google-sheets, graph, charts, google-query-language

Based on one cell with dates (some of them repeats multiple times):

- 06.02.2022
- 06.02.2022
- 08.02.2022
- 10.02.2022
- 17.02.2022

How to create the Google Sheets chart, where line goes up only when calendar day is exist in cell (and goes up multiply, based on x times when date repeats in cell)?

As a result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this will do:

```
=QUERY(A1:A; "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=SORT({QUERY(A1:A; "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''"); 
 QUERY(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1; 1; MIN(A:A))*{1\0}; 
 "where not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; N(A:A))&"'")}; 1; 1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: All missed days in array got to count as 0's on chart